# How do I selectively print parts of web pages with Prototype JS?

Tags: javascript, printing, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm still relatively new to Prototype JS. I spent a good portion of the day yesterday trying to find an existing library/extension to Prototype that enables selectively printing sections of a web page. I found something similar written for jQuery in the [jqPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) plug-in. However, I couldn't seem to find anything comparable for Prototype. Before I try to re-invent the wheel, I wanted to see if anybody else had found something along the lines of what I'm looking for. While using the jqPrint and jQuery libraries would be nice, unfortunately I can't do that. My work environment long ago decided to go with Prototype so that's what I'm stuck with for the time being.

Thanks in advance for whatever help is offered!

Rick

Answer (score 0):

If the selected part never changes then ignore Javascript (which is over-engineering and over-kill) and use CSS with a `media="print"` attribute or `@media print` rule.

Comment: Hi Clockwork. I know that would be the simple way, but I don't know that it would scale well for the purpose I have in mind. I'm displaying a dynamic datagrid of classes that individuals have registered and taken. I'd like the end-user to be able to generate and print out certificates of completion. Looking at jqPrint, it would be very easy to dynamically create a hidden iframe element, populate it with the necessary information, and have only that selected element print out. I may end up having to port it to Prototype, just wanted to see if it hadn't already been done in some fashion.

Comment: An iframe isn't difficult with [`clone()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/clone/) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML). In the past I have written many such stylesheets that hide headers, footers, menus, everything except a container around the data and I know it works well. It also works with the browser's existing print button, you don't have to (and cannot) catch that button event. The downside to a CSS approach is it's limited to one per page.

Comment: Yeah, and the one per page thing is the killer there. I decided yesterday to start working on a port of jqPrint to Prototype. Once I get it working I'll post it so that the community can utilize and/or optimize it. Thanks again Clockwork!